# How can I identify my Wear Node in my Mobile with multiple connected devices?

Tags: android, wear-os

In my Mobile this code will return all the nodes connected:

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Nodes: " + getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes());
    }
});
```

This is called for every node disconnected:

```
@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node peer) {    
   // Which peer is this?
}
```

Manual for onPeerDisconnected:

```
Notification that a peer has been disconnected from this node or is no 
longer reachable by this node.
Since multiple nodes can be connected to a network at the same time, 
peer connected and disconnected events can come in any order.
```

How would I know that my Wear was disconnected in my Mobile? And not any other connected device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we prefer to tag nodes not with their form factors "mobile/watch/..." but rather provide a way that each node can broadcast its "capabilities" and other nodes can query the network of connected devices to see which nodes provide the "capability" that they need. This is done by using the [CapabilityApis](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi). We use these APIs in some of the official samples so you can see them in action. As an example, your Phone App can broadcast that it supports "transcription capability" and your wear app can find those node(s) that provide that capability to decide where to send the voice streams for transcription. This provides a flexible and extensible framework that will continue to work when the ecosystem grows.

Answer (score 1):

What Ali said is very true, but if you really need the node of the device, there is an API for that too [`NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult).

Answer (score 1):

The following sections show you how to advertise device nodes that can process activity requests, discover the nodes capable of fulfilling a requested need, and send messages to those nodes,

**Advertise capabilities**

To launch an activity on a handheld device from a wearable device, use the MessageApi class to send the request. Since multiple wearables can be connected to the handheld device, the wearable app needs to determine that a connected node is capable of launching the activity. In your handheld app, advertise that the node it runs on provides specific capabilities.

To advertise the capabilities of your handheld app:

Create an XML configuration file in the res/values/ directory of your project and name it wear.xml.
Add a resource named android_wear_capabilities to wear.xml.
Define capabilities that the device provides.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>android_wear</item>
    </string-array> 
</resources>
```

**Retrieve the nodes with the required capabilities**

Initially, you can detect the capable nodes by calling the CapabilityApi.getCapability() method. The following example shows how to manually retrieve the results of reachable nodes with the android_wear capability. Use following code in Wear module:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity implements MessageApi.MessageListener, NodeApi.NodeListener,
    DataApi.DataListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String
        SMART_WEAR_CAPABILITY_NAME = "android_wear";

protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected ArrayList<String> results;
private String TAG = "BaseActivity::Wear";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

private Collection<String> getNodes() {
    results = new ArrayList<>();
    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes =
            Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();

    for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
        Log.d(TAG, node.getId());
        results.add(node.getId());
    }

    return results;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.NodeApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected(): Successfully connected to Google API client");
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.NodeApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    results = new ArrayList<>();

    getNodeIdOfHandheldDevice();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended(): Connection to Google API client was suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(): Failed to connect, with result: " + connectionResult);
}

@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onPeerConnected():");
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onPeerDisconnected():");
}

private void getNodeIdOfHandheldDevice() {
    Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(
            mGoogleApiClient, SMART_WEAR_CAPABILITY_NAME,
            CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        updateFindMeCapability(result.getCapability());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG,
                                "setOrUpdateNotification() Failed to get capabilities, "
                                        + "status: "
                                        + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void updateFindMeCapability(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
    Set<Node> connectedNodes = capabilityInfo.getNodes();
    if (connectedNodes.isEmpty()) {
        results.clear();
    } else {
        for (Node node : connectedNodes) {
            // we are only considering those nodes that are directly connected
            if (node.isNearby()) {
                results.add(node.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

For more detail please check [Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)